# textfield userinteractionenabled disable also input obj c

Tags: objective-c, textfield, user-interaction

I have a textfield with left and right view, I need to disable the touch on the text but not on the right view which allows me to delete the character entered with the custom keyboard. for this I have to disable input only of textfiel .. is it possible?

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIbX2.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure it is. Some ideas:

1. Add a new `UIView` subview to your textview on top covering the part that's meant to "ignore" user touches. Set its background to `clearColor` so that the text view is actually visible (during debugging a solid color like red may be actually helpful before you're happy with the final size & positioning). A small drawback of this approach is frames are rectangles, so area above and below the button would still accept user input (that may or may not make a difference in your case).
2. The other way round. Put the textfield view in a container view (also background color set to clear color), make the container frame smaller then the textview. Set the `origin.x` of the textfield frame to negative number. Set container view clip to bounds to `NO`.Eventually you want the container view to match your back button and position textview accordingly. You need also need passthrough touch events to textfield:

in container view from 2)

```
-(BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
        return NO;
}
```

Now only your area of the text view within container view will accept touches.